# How do I resolve pip install gevent error on Mac OS Mojave?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, gevent

I am a python newbie. I opened an existing project in Pycharm on Mac OS and got this error:

[image]

```
$ brew install pip

Error: No available formula with the name "pip"
pip is part of the python formula:
  brew install python

$ brew install python3

Error: python 3.7.2_1 is already installed
To upgrade to 3.7.2_2, run `brew upgrade python`

$ /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/libexec/bin/pip install gevent==1.2.2

Collecting gevent==1.2.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/92/b111f76e54d2be11375b47b213b56687214f258fd9dae703546d30b837be/gevent-1.2.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.4.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gevent==1.2.2) (0.4.15)
Building wheels for collected packages: gevent
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for gevent ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-install-2sumork0/gevent/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-wheel-kfxv6brw --python-tag cp37:
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'cffi_modules'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/greenlet.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/backdoor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_semaphore.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/pywsgi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/event.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/thread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_util_py2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/signal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_ssl3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/builtins.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/local.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/threadpool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/subprocess.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_socketcommon.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/timeout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/os.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_ssl2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/fileobject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_fileobjectcommon.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/hub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_socket2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/threading.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/win32util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/resolver_ares.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/baseserver.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_fileobjectposix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/lock.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_sslgte279.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_socket3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/monkey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/select.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_threading.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/ssl.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/socket.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/resolver_thread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/wsgi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/_tblib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/_corecffi_build.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/corecffi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  running egg_info
  writing src/gevent.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/gevent.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src/gevent.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src/gevent.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/gevent.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching 'changelog.rst'
  warning: no files found matching 'known_failures.py'
  warning: no files found matching '.pep8'
  no previously-included directories found matching '*/__pycache__'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.o' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lo' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.la' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'config.log' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'config.status' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found under directory 'src/greentest'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'src/greentest/htmlcov'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'stamp-h?' found under directory 'deps/c-ares'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'ares_build.h.orig' found under directory 'deps/c-ares'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'deps/libev/.deps'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'Makefile' found under directory 'deps/libev'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'libtool' found under directory 'deps/libev'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'stamp-h?' found under directory 'deps/libev'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'config.h' found under directory 'deps/libev'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '_corecffi.c' found under directory 'src/gevent'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'Makefile'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'configure-output'
  writing manifest file 'src/gevent.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying src/gevent/_semaphore.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/ares.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/cares.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/cares_ntop.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/cares_pton.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/dnshelper.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/gevent._semaphore.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/gevent.ares.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/gevent.ares.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/python.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying src/gevent/libev/_corecffi_cdef.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/_corecffi_source.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/callbacks.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/callbacks.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/corecext.ppyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/corecext.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/libev.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/libev.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/libev_vfd.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  copying src/gevent/libev/stathelper.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
  running build_ext
  Running '(cd  "/private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-install-2sumork0/gevent/deps/libev"  && sh ./configure   && cp config.h "$OLDPWD" ) > configure-output.txt' in /private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-install-2sumork0/gevent/build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/libev
  building 'gevent.libev.corecext' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/src
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/src/gevent
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/src/gevent/libev
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -U__llvm__ -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/libev -I/private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-install-2sumork0/gevent/deps/libev -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.o
  In file included from src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:434:
  In file included from src/gevent/libev/libev.h:2:
  /private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-install-2sumork0/gevent/deps/libev/ev.c:483:48: warning: '/*' within block comment [-Wcomment]
  /*#define MIN_INTERVAL  0.00000095367431640625 /* 1/2**20, good till 2200 */
                                                 ^
  /private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-install-2sumork0/gevent/deps/libev/ev.c:1269:13: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
        if (e < (14 - 24)) /* might not be sharp, but is good enough */
            ~ ^  ~~~~~~~
  /private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-install-2sumork0/gevent/deps/libev/ev.c:1831:31: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    EV_API_DECL struct ev_loop *ev_default_loop_ptr = 0; /* needs to be initialised to make it a definition despite extern */
                                ^
  /private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-install-2sumork0/gevent/deps/libev/ev.c:1940:19: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
    if (elem * ncur > MALLOC_ROUND - sizeof (void *) * 4)
        ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-install-2sumork0/gevent/deps/libev/ev.c:3878:34: warning: '&' within '|' [-Wbitwise-op-parentheses]
    fd_change (EV_A_ fd, w->events & EV__IOFDSET | EV_ANFD_REIFY);
                         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~
  /private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-install-2sumork0/gevent/deps/libev/ev.c:3878:34: note: place parentheses around the '&' expression to silence this warning
    fd_change (EV_A_ fd, w->events & EV__IOFDSET | EV_ANFD_REIFY);
                                   ^
                         (                      )
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:3314:104: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
    __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_f_6gevent_5libev_8corecext__flags_to_int(__pyx_v_flags, 0); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_1 == -1 && PyErr_Occurred())) __PYX_ERR(0, 168, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                                               ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:614:43: note: expanded from macro 'unlikely'
    #define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
                                            ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:4092:106: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
      __pyx_t_2 = __pyx_f_6gevent_5libev_8corecext__flags_to_int(__pyx_v_flags, 0); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_2 == -1 && PyErr_Occurred())) __PYX_ERR(0, 267, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:614:43: note: expanded from macro 'unlikely'
    #define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
                                            ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30323:65: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 3, have 4
      return (*((__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)meth)) (self, args, nargs, NULL);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                     ^~~~
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:105:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
  #  define NULL ((void*)0)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30535:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      *type = tstate->exc_type;
              ~~~~~~  ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30536:22: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      *value = tstate->exc_value;
                       ^~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30537:19: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30544:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                 ~~~~~~  ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30545:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30546:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30547:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tstate->exc_type = type;
      ~~~~~~  ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30548:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tstate->exc_value = value;
              ^~~~~~~~~
              curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30549:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
              curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30604:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                 ~~~~~~  ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30605:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30606:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30607:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tstate->exc_type = local_type;
      ~~~~~~  ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30608:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tstate->exc_value = local_value;
              ^~~~~~~~~
              curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:30609:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
              curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:31158:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                 ~~~~~~  ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:31159:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:31160:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  7 warnings and 20 errors generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for gevent
  Running setup.py clean for gevent
Failed to build gevent
Installing collected packages: gevent
  Running setup.py install for gevent ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-install-2sumork0/gevent/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/0f/bp0p28fn5n9bwtg6wt7bs8nm0000gn/T/pip-record-rdykn6v0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'cffi_modules'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/greenlet.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/backdoor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_semaphore.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/pywsgi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/event.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/thread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_util_py2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/signal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_ssl3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/builtins.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/local.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/threadpool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/subprocess.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_socketcommon.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/timeout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/os.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_ssl2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/fileobject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_fileobjectcommon.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/hub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_socket2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/threading.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/win32util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/resolver_ares.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/baseserver.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_fileobjectposix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/lock.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_sslgte279.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_socket3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/monkey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/select.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_threading.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/ssl.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/socket.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/resolver_thread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/wsgi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    copying src/gevent/_tblib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
    copying src/gevent/libev/_corecffi_build.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
    copying src/gevent/libev/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
    copying src/gevent/libev/corecffi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gevent/libev
    running egg_info
    writing src/gevent.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/gevent.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to src/gevent.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to src/gevent.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/gevent.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'changelog.rst'
    warning: no files found matching 'known_failures.py'
    warning: no files found matching '.pep8'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/__pycache__'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.o' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.la' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found under directory 'src/greentest'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'src/greentest/htmlcov'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'stamp-h?' found under directory 'deps/c-ares'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'ares_build.h.orig' found under directory 'deps/c-ares'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '_corecffi.c' found under directory 'src/gevent'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'Makefile'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'configure-output'

...
```

https://pastebin.com/LF76EK2N

Looks like both python2 and python3 are installed on my mac:

```
$ /usr/bin/python --version

Python 2.7.10

$ /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/libexec/bin/python --version

Python 3.7.2
```

Comment: *`gevent==1.2.2`* Why do you use such an old version? The current version is 1.4.0.

Comment: I am using the sample apps that are in the istio-1.0.5 release. Just trying to run the apps. I didn't write that code. It is open-source.

Comment: Also I am a big fan of using miniconda for python.  Makes all of this far more easier.

Answer (score 2):

The error "no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'" comes from Python 3.7. You're trying to install rather old version of `gevent` (1.2.2) that doesn't support Python 3.7. Use Python 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6. Even the latest version of `gevent` (currently 1.4.0) [doesn't support Python 3.7 yet](https://pypi.org/project/gevent/1.4.0/#supported-platforms).